# Cannot connect database using picocli and micronaut

Tags: kotlin, micronaut, micronaut-data, picocli

I using picocli connect database and build native images. I using micronaut connect to postgres get some data when i excute images native build by picocli. But i have problem when using entityManager. When i using entity manager using @Inject it always throw me exception

```
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property entityManager has not been initialized
```

By code bellow

```
@Singleton
class StudentRepository  {

    @Inject
    lateinit var entityManager: EntityManager


    @ReadOnly
    fun findAll(): List<Student?>? {
        var qlString = "SELECT * FROM Student as g"

        val query: TypedQuery<Student> = entityManager.createQuery(qlString, Student::class.java)
        return query.getResultList()
    }

}
```

Then service i call look like

```
@CommandLine.Command(name = "studentService", description = arrayOf("Student service"),mixinStandardHelpOptions = true)
@Singleton
class StudentService(): Runnable {
     @Inject
    lateinit var studentRepository: StudentRepository

 override fun run() {
        getAllStudent()
 }

 fun getAllStudent() {
     println("Count student ${studentRepository.findAll().size}")
  }

}
```

My application

```
@picocli.CommandLine.Command(
    name = "cli",
    description = ["Cli"],
    version = ["Cli"],
    mixinStandardHelpOptions = true,
    subcommands = [StudentService::class]
)
class MyApplication : Runnable {

    override fun run() {
        println("Begin start")
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    PicocliRunner.run(MyApplication::class.java, *args)
}
```

But if i using http client it work.
https://dev.to/stack-labs/cli-applications-with-micronaut-and-picocli-4mc8
I don't know why cannot using entityManager . How to connect db using picocli

Comment: Can you get the EntityManager injection to work in a simple program without picocli? Maybe in a JUnit test or something? Just to confirm that picocli is actually causing or even related to the problem.

Comment: Well when i check some case , if inside main function i remove  PicocliRunner.run(MyApplication::class.java, *args) and change it to commandLine CommandLine(MyApplication()).execute(*args) when i inject base on  https://dev.to/stack-labs/cli-applications-with-micronaut-and-picocli-4mc8  it don't work. I think it dependent PicocliRunner. PicocliRunner build all dependency and inject it . But i don't know why HttpClient work but some case like : CrudRepository or entityManager not working

Comment: No, that’s not what I meant. If you replace PicocliRunner by CommandLine.execute, you will have removed _Micronaut_, not picocli. I want to try the opposite: Can you make a simple Micronaut application (without picocli) that successfully injects EntityManager?

Comment: Now it working ? So i have a question you can help me 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67293646/how-to-using-parent-command-into-subcommand-picocli